# Detect automatic item selection in a Listbox using Tkinter

Tags: python, events, tkinter, listbox

I mean, for Buttons you can write something like this:

```
def addItem():
    pass
addbtn = Button(mainFrame, text = "Add Item", command = addItem)
```

How can I do the same thing for a Listbox? Like this one for example:

```
def on_selection():
    pass
list = Listbox(mainFrame, selectmode = SINGLE, command = on_selection) # This doesn't work.
```

The point is that the binding `mainFrame.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", on_selection)` **doesn't works when I select an item automatically with `list.selection_set(selection)`**.

In other words **automatically trigger the on_selection() function when list.selection_set(...) is called** without overwriting the Listbox class or selection_set function. The goal is to write one line instead of

```
list.selection_set(selct)
on_selection()
```

every time.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://pastebin.com/9JDwhMrx)?

Comment: No, I wonder if exist a way to automatically trigger the `on_selection()` function when `list.selection_set(...)` is called without overwriting the Listbox class or selection_set function. The goal is to write one line instead of `list.selection_set(selct); on_selection();` every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def on_selection(event):
  print(dir(event))

def some_nonevent():
  print(str(2 + 2))

listbox = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode=tk.SINGLE, activestyle='none')
for name in ['john', 'tim', 'sam', 'jill', 'sandra']:
  listbox.insert(tk.END, name)

listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_selection)

listbox.selection_set(3)

listbox.grid()

with open('myfile.py') as f:
  contents = f.read()
  if '\nlistbox.selection_set(2)\n' in contents:
    listbox.event_generate('<<ListboxSelect>>')
    some_nonevent()
  else:
    print('do nothing')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I would like that if I write `listbox.selection_set(2)` this will trigger the on_selection() function

Comment: I have a feeling that what you *think* you *need* probably isn't what you actually *need* to achieve whatever your end-goal is. If I understand you, you want to run a script that looks at the script **code** itself to see if you wrote `listbox.selection_set(2)` and if found, trigger a function. I modified the above to read the file and look for the string.

Comment: You're right, probably the best solution is to ovewrite the selection_set function in the Listbox class and make it trigger the function.